# What will be the $\oint \zeta (z)^{-1} dz$ over a circle of finite and infinite radius?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So basically, I did actually try finding the answer by using Cauchy's residue theorem, but the result is rather big (which is completely fine), but when when I do the normal $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(iRe^{iθ})}{ζ(Re^iθ)}dz$$ for, say, $R=15$ it gives me a really small value when I compute it on WolframAlpha. I know if I pick $R$ as an even number, there will be a singularity at $\theta = \pi$, but this is the case even with odd $R$, moreover the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(iRe^{iθ})}{ζ(Re^iθ)}dz$$ should remain same for a pair of odd and even $R$s (for small $R$s) because $$\frac{1}{ζ(Re^{iθ})}$$ has singularities only at a bunch of complex numbers, and at negative even integers.
Did I do something wrong, or maybe it is a problem with the computation instead?

Edit: I think many of you didn't get the question. What I've been trying to say is that $\oint \zeta (z)^{-1} dz = 2πi\sum_{ρ} {\frac{1}{ζ′(ρ)}}$ is not equal to $$\int_0^\infty \frac{(iRe^{iθ})}{ζ(Re^iθ)}dz$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You did a good job with the maths actually. The only “problem” is that you’re using Unicode characters when you can just write `$\zeta,\theta,\pi$` to render the relevant letters. More generally, `$\something$` is likely to render any common function, operator or symbol, perhaps with an abbreviation

Comment: MathJax works in the title section too . . .

Comment: For $r$ not the absolute value of a zero and assuming that all the non-trivial zeros are simple we get $\int_{|s|=r} \frac1{\zeta(s)}ds = 2i\pi \sum_{|\rho|< r} \frac1{\zeta'(\rho)}$